# Why print (@ARGV), "\n" doesn't print the newline in Perl?

Tags: perl

What's the reason that

```
print (@ARGV), "\n";
```

doesn't print the ending newline but

```
print @ARGV, "\n";
```

does? I'd assume the parenthesis would be neutral in this case? Or even if they are tupling the `@ARGV` why would they make print chop off the newline anyway?

Thanks

Comment: `use warnings;` tells you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ perl -we'print (@ARGV), "\n";'
print (...) interpreted as function at -e line 1.
Useless use of a constant (
) in void context at -e line 1.
```

There's no difference between

```
print (@ARGV), "\n";
```

and

```
print(@ARGV), "\n";
```

So you're doing

```
print(@ARGV); "\n";
```

Solutions:

```
print +(@ARGV), "\n";
print @ARGV, "\n";
print((@ARGV), "\n");
print(@ARGV, "\n");
...
```

Comment: If that's not 100% clear: the statement is saying 'evaluate the print() function for \@ARGV, then evaluate the string expression "\n"'. The print() prints \@ARGV, and the expression "\n" is simply evaluated and discarded.

Answer (score 5):

Parentheses never tuple in perl.  They only determine precedence and synxtax.

print() is a subroutine call, passing what is in the parentheses to print.  Even with a space before it.  When you have a space before the parentheses, this may not be what you intend, so perl will warn you...if you enable warnings.  It will also warn you that the "\n" is useless because it is in void context.

```
$ perl -we'print (@ARGV), "\n"'
print (...) interpreted as function at -e line 1.
Useless use of a constant ("\n") in void context at -e line 1.
```